# Set Wallpaper from webview URL

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to setup a application to load URL in Webview and then give the application the ability to set any image that is clicked to be set as a wallpaper.

So far I am able to load the URL and display the gallery.

I am pretty much stuck on how to set the click-able image was wallpaper.

Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

```
    package com.dg.rWallpapers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class rWallpapersActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        /* mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); */ //Removed I do not want zooming.
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://wall.dg.net?wallId=5");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient(this));

        // Lookup R.layout.main
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad);

        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxx");

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
        //request.setTesting(true);

        adView.loadAd(request);

    }


    public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        private WallpaperManager mWallpaperManager;
        private Context mContext;

        public HelloWebViewClient(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                try {
                    Bitmap b = downloadImage(url);
                    mWallpaperManager.setBitmap(b);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private Bitmap downloadImage(String fileUrl) throws IOException {
            try {
                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URL(fileUrl).toURI());
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
                BufferedHttpEntity buffer = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer.getContent());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and implement the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method to handle a click on your images in the activity. There, you can download the image and set it as a wallpaper.

Here is an example for such a `WebViewClient`:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    private WallpaperManager mWallpaperManager;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyWebViewClient(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".jpg") || url.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
            new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {
                        return downloadImage(params[0]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        try {
                            mWallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }.execute(url);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Bitmap downloadImage(String fileUrl) throws IOException {
        try {
            HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URL(fileUrl).toURI());
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
            BufferedHttpEntity buffer = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer.getContent());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You add the WebViewClient to your WebView via `setWebClient(new MyWebViewClient(this))` in your activity.

Comment: do you have an example, or sample code?? I am totally new to android development. BTW I already have it as setWebClient()

Comment: Okay I got this part going:

        `public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
            if( url.contains(".png") || url.contains(".jpg") || url.contains(".jpeg") ){
                // do whatever you want
            }
        }`

Comment: I am getting few error. I did everything and even imported all files needed.

Comment: SDK 3.2 = 13 . I posted the error above. Is there anyway we can exchange skype or gtalk. I really need help.

Comment: I have added my entire java file up-top.

Comment: I have narrow it down to AsyncTask class, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I can't test it myself because http://wall.dg.net?wallId=5 isn't available for me. However, if I download other pictures, it works...

Comment: @GianU. I have some questions could you please explain 
1)How we can download or set as wallpaper image from webview is there any button or we need to long press for same?
2)How we can handle if there are multiple images in webview?
3)Where image will be store (folder name)?